# Suggestion about file reader tool implementation

Tags: c++

Say I need to implement a tool that always read & update a file.
The tool is text based and taking commands to perform from the command line.

If the tool always read & write data to and from the DB (The DB is just files in this case) , should I include any data-structures in the main memory to make it easier?

I thought about just making an interpreter that just reads the command, parse it and perform it. Also, when there is a request for data , the tool just go over the file and grab the required data (without saving any of it in a data structure).

Keep in mind that the tool always update its DB whenever required so ill also have to update the data structures every time it updates his DB.

Bottom line is, is that a good idea to go over the file and grab the information every time it is required or I should just make data-structures within the program to make it faster and easier to keep the data?

The interpreter class (struct in this case) is something like :

```
struct Interpreter {

virtual void interpret(const std::string& cmd) = 0;

};
```

The concrete interpreter inherits from it.

would love to hear some suggestions.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use boost:
 - [program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html) to read the command line
 - [filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) to read the file path

As for whether you read the file or cache it? You say: "have to update the data structures every time it updates his DB". I read from this that you *must* read the files every time, to be consistent with his DB.

Even if you find that you need to cache the files to improve performance, remember the old adage: "it's easier to make working code fast, than to make fast code to work!"